# How to get short month names in Joda Time?

Tags: java, time, jodatime

Does anyone know if there's a method in Joda Time or Java itself which takes either an int or a String as an argument, e.g. 4 or "4" and gives the name of the month back in short format, i.e. JAN for January?

I suppose long month names can be truncated and converted to upper case.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In response to Jon's answer, you can further simplify that by using Joda's direct access for datetime classes.

```
String month = date.toString("MMM");
```

Comment: Or `String month = date.toString("MMM", Locale.US)` for a specific locale.

Answer (score 18):

I believe "MMM" will give the month name in Joda... but you'd need to build up an appropriate formatter first. Here's some sample code which prints "Apr" on my box. (You can specify the relevant locale of course.)

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Year and day will be ignored
        LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2010, 4, 1);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM");
        String month = formatter.print(date);
        System.out.println(month);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We can do as following:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();  // current time
String monthStr = dt.month().getAsShortText();  // gets the month name
```

Also you can use `getAsText()` method for long month name.

[Reference](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_instant.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalDateTime fecha_sistema = LocalDateTime.now();

// return month value betwen 1 to 12
int month = fecha_sistema.getMonthValue();

// return month name
String mes = fecha_sistema.getMonth().name();

System.out.println("Month" + mes + "/ " + month);
```

Answer (score -2):

My last answer about using `java.util.Calendar` for this was a little more complicated than it needed to be.  Here's a simpler version, although it still requires Java 6 or newer.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Sample usage.
        // Should be "Apr" in English languages
        String month = getMonthNameShort(4);
        System.out.println(month);
    }
    /**
     * @param month Month number
     * @return The short month name
     */
    public static String getMonthNameShort(int month)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Calendar numbers months from 0
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
        return cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please delete this. The question asked for JodaTime

Comment: @cricket_007 "Does anyone know if there's a method in Joda Time or Java itself" <-- directly from the question.  `Calendar` is from Java itself.

Comment: Ah, well. By bad for just seeing the question text and tags. I'll revert downvote for updating with `java.time` at least